# Can I load CodeIgniter view from ajax response and use $data obj?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Alright, so my loaded view uses data that it receives from the controller. I then use a jquery .change listener to listen for a change in a select-option list. That will then trigger a function to run and essentially an ajax request will be sent to a function I have in the controller. In that function I need to try and 'reload' the data that was loaded through the controllers index, but with new parameters based on the value of the dropdown list. As of right now the initial page load with data is working fine. The jquery .change and ajax request are also working, however, the controller function is not resetting the pages data. Here is what I have...any help would be much appreciated.

jQuery (which is in my members_home.php view):

```
$('#folder_select').change(function() {
    var data = $('#folder_select').val();
    loadTables(data);
});

function loadTables(str) {
    console.log("dfgdfg");
    $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url().'account/members_home/folderSelector';?>', 
            type: 'POST',
            data: { folderCat: str },
            success: function(output_string){

            }
    }); 
}
```

Members_home.php View (html):

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <th width="50%">File Name:</th>
        <th width="30%">File Size:</th>
        <th>Download Link:</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $c = true;
    foreach((array)$things as $files){
         if (!empty($files) > 0) {
             if ($files['size'] >= 1000000000) {
                $files['size'] = round( ($files['size'] / 1000000000) , 2).' GB';
             }
             else if ($files['size'] >= 1000000) {
                    $files['size'] = round( ($files['size'] / 1000000) , 2).' MB';
             }else{
                $files['size'] = round( ($files['size'] / 1000) , 2).' KB';
             }

            echo '<tr'.(($c = !$c)?' class="odd"':'').">
                <td>$files[name]</td>
                <td>$files[size]</td>
                <td><a href='$files[location]' >Download</a></td>
            </tr>";
         }else {
            echo '<tr><td colspan="3">Folder is empty.</td></tr>';
             break;
         }
    } ?>

 </table><br />
```

Members_home Controller:

```
function index()
{
    $is_logged_in = $this->loggedin->loggedin();
    if(!$is_logged_in)
    {
        redirect('account/createaccount', 'refresh');
    }
    else
    {   
        $q = $this->account_model->folder();
        $data['folder'] = $q;

        // This part gets the data that's used in the html table
        $userID = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $data['things'] = $this->account_model->folder_Homepage($userID);

        $data['main_content'] = 'account/members_home';
        $this->load->view('includes/template2', $data);
    }
}

// This function is used during the ajax request
public function folderSelector()
{
    $fID = $this->input->post('folderCat');
    $limit = 10;
    $userID = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $data['things'] = $this->account_model->folder_page($fID, $userID, $limit);

    // This is the part that is not working, shouldn't I be able to reload 
    // $data['things'] and send it to the view with the new parameters?
    $data['main_content'] = 'account/members_home';
    $this->load->view('includes/template2', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller methods look correct. The `$data['things']` in the `folderSelector` method is used correctly - each method call (from a separate request - like an ajax request) doesn't know about the others, so you do need to call the model to set `$data['things']`.

Your ajax success handler doesn't do anything with the returned data though. You should change the `loadTables` function to:

```
function loadTables(str) {
    console.log("dfgdfg");
    $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url().'account/members_home/folderSelector';?>', 
            type: 'POST',
            data: { folderCat: str },
            success: function(output_string){
                // here you need to inject the new data in the page 
                // in place of the old data
                $('table').replaceWith(output_string);
            }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: output string wouldn't be anything though...because folderSelector doesn't return anything. It's sole purpose is to reload data['things'] with the new parameters.

Comment: but it's output should be the HTML for the table - maybe try this:  `echo $this->load->view('includes/template2', $data, TRUE);` at the end of the `folderSelector` method.

Comment: $data['things'] isn't the table..it's just holds the variables that the View would use

Comment: right, but then you're passing that to the view which is then output with the line: `$this->load->view('includes/template2', $data);` - so calling this method via a URL, would output the template2 view with the new `$things` data.

Comment: I got it!! You were really close: $('table').replaceWith(output_string);   needs to be changes to $('table').html(output_string);